# Can I get legible output out of webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I want to split my Typescript code into modules for maintainability, and join them into a single compiled JavaScript file for the browser.  Webpack sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, as it will transpile my Typescript, combine the modules, and I can easily have separate build tasks for development and production, choosing whether to minify, cache-bust, watch for file changes, etc.  I also want to bundle some of my modules separately, to load dynamically, which isn't hard to configure.  And it can handle my CSS too, including compiling from Sass.  One tool to do all this?  Where do I sign up?

But I was a little disillusioned when I saw the JavaScript that webpack created.  I can live with the boilerplate that it adds to the top, all though it's a bit more than I expected.  And the minified version is practically impossible to reconstruct into something comprehensible, but that can be considered a feature, right?

What bothers me is that the development build is practically unrecognizable compared to the source, and the code is loaded via a huge ugly `eval` string.  And it doesn't seem to add any of my exports to `window` object, so I can't access anything from the browser's console.  So the generated code is not only pretty opaque, but debugging is a lot harder (even with source maps).

Is there some way I can configure it to give me debug output that is any easier to read and debug?

Here's my simple configuration for testing:

```js
// ./webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./ts/main.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./js")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"]
    }
};
```

```json
// ./tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

For demonstration, I've got a very bare test file:

```
// ./ts/main.ts

export function hello(){return "Hello, World!";}

console.log(hello());
```

I don't want to paste the entire output here, because it's too much to ask anybody to scroll past, so [here it is on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/serowefuzo/edit?js).  But to summarize it briefly, it's kind of like this:

```js
// ./js/main.js

/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
// ....... snip 76 lines ....... 
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./ts/main.ts");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./ts/main.ts":
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ./ts/main.ts ***!
  \********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__
// ....... snip 223 characters .......
function hello() { return \"Hello, World!\"; }\n    exports.hello = hello;\n    console.log(hello());\n}).apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__),
// ....... Hey, there's my code! .......
// ....... snip 133 more characters
// //# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64
// ....... snip the source map data (gobbledygook that's actually useful)
");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

Now if I embed this in an HTML file and load it into a browser ...

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I see my console log, but I can't access my function.

[image: JavaScript console]

Comment: If you want to debug, you just simply add `devtool: "source-map"` to debug in your browser easy. Plus, the module is private so in order to public in your browser, you can public via `global` value :)

Comment: @tmhao2005: Thanks, that's a good start.  I don't actually have to add `devtool: "source-map"`.  It's already writing an inline source map (see the js output).  But it's the compiled JavaScript, which is a little messy because it includes export cruft, but already a huge improvement.  However, if I add `"sourceMap": true` to `tsconfig.json`, I actually get the original TypeScript source.  But what I didn't realize is that I have to look under `webpack://` in Chrome's Sources tab in order to find it.

Comment: @tmhao2005: But I don't understand the second part of what you said: "public via `global` value".

Comment: Some module formats create global variables. Webpack can create a UMD bundle or an IIFE bundle if you want to but you shouldn't want it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle generated by webpack is not meant to be inspectable by humans, at least not directly. This is even true in development.

Webpack has a [`devtool` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) that tells it to output [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/). This allows you to inspect code that looks like your original source in the browser's debugger, even though the code the browser is executing is different.

Webpacked code must be different than the source. You may write `import './foo'` but `foo.js` is not a separate file in the bundle, it's just a portion of the code in that bundle. So webpack rewrites that `import` to work in a different way.

And typescript works similarly. It supports features that not all browsers may support, and the typescript compiler translates that stuff to something most browsers can deal with, sometimes very verbosely.

---

Lastly, this is a separate issue:

> And it doesn't seem to add any of my exports to window object

This is *by design*.

Exporting something from a file will never add to the global scope. This keeps the global scope clean. If you want something in the global scope, you'll need to put it there explicitly:

```
window.foo = { abc: 123 }
```

But usually, the idea here is that other modules in you bundle can import modules and use their code without anything ever being in the global scope.

```
import foo from './foo'

console.log(foo.abc)
```

Now if you have code outside your bundle, that depends on code inside your bundle that obviously gets tricky, and you'd need to explicitly assign values to the global scope. But more commonly, you just import the module you need from a module that will also be in the same bundle, and you keep the global scope completely unpolluted.